# Can we merge the tags speech-to-text and voice command into "speech recognition"?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

I've just created a tag wiki for [speech-recognition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition) (<s>should be under review by now</s>).

I propose that we merge [speech-to-text](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speech-to-text) and [speech-recognition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition) into [speech-recognition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition) because it is the most commonly used term for this kind of technology. (I deal a lot with speech recognition professionally and all the English language forums nowadays call it speech recognition.) FWIW, the Wikipedia entry also lists speech recognition.

Possibly, to prevent future complications, let us also use [voice-recognition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/voice-recognition) - currently non-existant - as a tag synonym for [speech-recognition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition).

EDIT:

I leave the previously proposed merge of  [voice-commands](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/voice-commands) open for discussion, because while voice commands are part of speech recognition, they can also exist in software not intended for text creation - such as Dragon oder Windows Speech Recognition, but in "pure" command tools like Speakable Items on Mac. However, some people might associate voice-commands with speech recognition for text creation - because you command the computer to write.

My argument in favor or merging [voice-commands](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/voice-commands) with [speech-recognition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition) is that both categories exist in small numbers, so an overly fine distinction is not warranted. However, the "small-number argument" might not be considered relevant by others.

[text-to-speech](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/text-to-speech) (TTS) should not be merged because it describes a different technology. [speech](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/speech) should not be merged either, because it most often used in the contect of TTS on this site.

Comment: Speech recognition includes voice commands, but is not synonymous. For example, dictation is speech recognition, but is commonly not considered the same as voice commands. Right?

Comment: @ivan voice commands is part of speech recognition, you're right. There are few applications however that offer voice commands but no speech recognition. On a dedicated speech recognition site it would be useful to keep 2 tags, but on SU I don't think the number of voice-command related question warrants a separate tag.

Comment: But such specificity is not nearly as problematic as the unnecessary differentiation between speech-to-text and speech-recognition, right? Also, you say "few applications (…) offer voice commands but no speech recognition"; OS X only since Mountain Lion includes dictation, and even that is performed on servers, not locally. So it's distinct stuff. Dunno, it doesn't seem useful to merge tags like these where distinction does exist. It's confusing to new or occasional visitors of the community (like me), and does little to help regular users.